# How to add borders to the table design

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have created the table design and I want white lines to separate the columns similar to rows. I tried to do so but couldn't able to figure it out.

This is my table design:

[image]

Expected design: (I have tried to illustrate the design ignore my drawing)

[image]

Below is the code. How can I solve this?

```html
<style>
    .styled-table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 25px 0;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      min-width: 400px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    .styled-table thead tr {
      background-color: #4e5051d3;
      color: #fdfdfd;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .styled-table td {
      color: #fdfdfd;
    }
    .styled-table th,
    .styled-table td {
      padding: 12px 15px;
    }

    .styled-table tbody tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }

    .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd),
    .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: #0a0b0be4;
    }

    
  </style>

    <div>
      <table class="styled-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashish</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yadnesh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>88000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vinit</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>70000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Pushkar</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>84000</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- and so on... -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `style`:

```css
    th{
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: white;
    }
    tr{
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: white;
    }
    td{
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

border-left on th/td ? If i understood the question.

```html
<style>
    .styled-table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 25px 0;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      min-width: 400px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    .styled-table thead tr {
      background-color: #4e5051d3;
      color: #fdfdfd;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .styled-table td {
      color: #fdfdfd
    }
    .styled-table th,
    .styled-table td {
      padding: 12px 15px;;
       border-left: 1px solid #dddddd
    }

    .styled-table tbody tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }

    .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd),
    .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: #0a0b0be4;
    }

    
  </style>

    <div>
      <table class="styled-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashish</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yadnesh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>88000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vinit</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>70000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Pushkar</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>84000</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- and so on... -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you for the solution.